# Which event fires after using the Cancel command on a DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I need to perform a few checks (enable or disable a label elsewhere on the page) after the user Inserts or Cancels the DetailsView. I have to do this because the DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire during this event (which is dumb in my opinion, since the index DOES change).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ModeChanging should fire, so can you do this?

```
protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CancelingEdit)
    {
        //Checks
    }
}
```